# Laravel error: Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get a partner for each order using Laravel resource collections. But this throws up an error:

```
Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance
```

I get `partners` this way

**Order_product.php**

```
//...
class Order_product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'product_id', 'quantity', 'price'];

public function partner()
  {
   return $this->hasManyThrough(
         'App\Partner', 'App\Order',
      'partner_id', 'id', 'order_id');
        //orders  partners  order_products
   }
//...
```

**Resources\Order_product.php**

```
class Order_product extends JsonResource
{
   public function toArray($request)
    {
     return [
            'id'         => $this->id,
            'order_id'   => $this->order_id,
            'product_id' => $this->product_id,
            'quantity'   => $this->quantity,
            'price'      => $this->price,
            'status'     => $this->order->status,
          'product_name' => $this->prod->name,

           //return error
          'partner_name' => $this->partner->name,

         ];
/*
//this method return:
//Invalid argument supplied for foreach() {"exception":"[object]... 

$partners = [];

        foreach($this->collection as $partner) {

             array_push($partners, [

                // 'partner_name' => $this->partner->name
             ]);

        }

        return $partners;
*/
    }
}
```

Each order has one partner name.  In the future, I will group them, but now I just need to output the `partner_name`

Comment: you have collection in    'product_name' => $this->prod->name,

try n use $this->prod->first()->name;

Comment: @kunalrajput I fixed, but now have error: `Call to a member function first() on null {"exception":"[object]`

Answer (score 0):

is relations when you use `hasMany` or `hasManyThrough` it returns you a collection, so you should use it in **foreach** or use with **index**

```
return [
'product_name' => $this->prod->first()->name,  //first array in collection using first()
   ];
```

**OR**

```
return [
'product_name' => $this->prod[0]->name,  //first array in collection using index
   ];
```

or you can write this code in **foreach**!

Comment: I fixed, but now have error: `Call to a member function first() on null {"exception":"[object]` . And `partner_name` not `product_name`

Comment: please `die` or `dd` for every level of your function, first of all check what are you getting, for example `dd($this->prod);` and then you realize what should do next!

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `hasManyThrough` or `hasMany` laravel relationship returns `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` Instance.

If you want to get name you have to have one `Model` instance.

**Solution 1**: `$this->parthner->first()->name`

**Solution 2**: See this [hasOneThough](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_hasOneThrough)

```
public function partner(){
   return $this->hasOneThrough(
         'App\Partner', 'App\Order',
      'partner_id', 'id', 'order_id');
}
```

Depens on your app logic

Hope this helps you

Comment: I fixed it according to your edits, but now have error:`Call to a member function first() on null {"exception":"[object]`